# Rails: how to save an external web page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In a rails app, given an external URL, I need to make a local copy of web pages not created by my app.  Much like "save as" from a browser.  I looked into system("wget -r -l 1 http://google.com")  It might work, but it copies too much for the pages I tried (like 10x too much).  I need to follow the link references to stuff to make the page display properly, but don't want to follow all the a href's to other pages.  Any package out there?

Answer (score 0):

This `wget` command usually works for me, so maybe it will for you:

```
wget -nd -pHEKk "http://www.google.com/"
```

But once you get all the files, you'll have to parse them for references to the base url and replace that with `./`, which shouldn't be too hard (I don't do Ruby, so I'm not helping with that).

Answer (score 0):

You could also use something like [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/) or [HPricot](http://hpricot.com/). An example with Nokogiri:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open('http://www.google.com/'))
```

This will give you an actual Ruby object that can be 'queried' using the associated methods.